# Oracle/Hyperion XML Date Format

Tags: xml, oracle, datetime, xsd

I just received an XML file that was exported from Hyperion.  The XLM follows:

```
<DueDate date="1348257648893">
```

The value either represents September 21, 2012 or September 21, 2012 4:00PM.

Does anyone know what format this is and how I can translate it.  I have to create a new XML file containing a lot dates and need to be able to convert them to the correct format.

I've tried formatting it in Excel and tested several millisecond variants but have not been able to crack the code.

Thanks for your help

Comment: milliseconds from Jan 1st 1970?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the milliseconds from unix epoch date (Jan 1st 1970).

```
select to_date('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 1348257648893/(86400*1000) from dual;
```